# How can I get the device's ip on React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In node we would use `require('os')` but we cannot do such thing on react native. Any ideas?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There's a ReactNative library for getting information about the devices network:

[react-native-network-info](https://github.com/pusherman/react-native-network-info)

```
// require module
var NetworkInfo = require('react-native-network-info');

// Get Local IP
NetworkInfo.getIPAddress(ip => {
  console.log(ip);
});
```

Comment: This gets the local IP address not the external

Comment: Actually if you take a look at the native Java code that retrieves this IP, it iterates through all interfaces and returns the last valid IP. This means that if the device cached the IP or has more then one interface up and provides the IP on more then one device, you will get an invalid address. Hence this method is by definition flawed and works most of the time by accident. I have concrete devices that give me invalid IP addresses (mobile data iface instead of Wi-Fi) using this method.

Comment: You can try using following to get the public ip: NetworkInfo.getIPV4Address().then(ipv4Address => {
  console.log(ipv4Address);
});

Comment: Sorry what is the difference between the local IP and external IP ?

Comment: I think, @Nexus242 is more simpler and worked for me

Answer (score 22):

```
import publicIP from 'react-native-public-ip';

publicIP()
.then(ip => {    
  console.log(ip);
  // '47.122.71.234'
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
  // 'Unable to get IP address.'
});
```

For more info:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-public-ip

Comment: This returns public IP Address, should be an answer for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

This package gives following apis

```
npm i react-native-network-info



import { NetworkInfo } from "react-native-network-info";
 
// Get Local IP
NetworkInfo.getIPAddress().then(ipAddress => {
  console.log(ipAddress);
});
 
// Get IPv4 IP (priority: WiFi first, cellular second)
NetworkInfo.getIPV4Address().then(ipv4Address => {
  console.log(ipv4Address);
});
 
// Get Broadcast
NetworkInfo.getBroadcast().then(broadcast => {
  console.log(broadcast);
});
 
// Get SSID
NetworkInfo.getSSID().then(ssid => {
  console.log(ssid);
});
 
// Get BSSID
NetworkInfo.getBSSID().then(bssid => {
  console.log(bssid);
});
 
// Get Subnet
NetworkInfo.getSubnet().then(subnet => {
  console.log(subnet);
});
 
// Get Default Gateway IP
NetworkInfo.getGatewayIPAddress().then(defaultGateway => {
  console.log(defaultGateway);
});
 
// Get frequency (supported only for Android)
NetworkInfo.getFrequency().then(frequency => {
  console.log(frequency);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to offer another library: https://github.com/react-native-netinfo/react-native-netinfo#netinfostate

This one has slightly more features and it looks like there's a bigger community using it.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Latest updated soln without library:

```
fetch('https://ipapi.co/json/')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log('ipapi_getIpAddressgetIpAddress', data);
    Alert.alert('ipapi', JSON.stringify(data));
  }); //paid after some usage

fetch('https://api.ipify.org?format=json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log('apiv4_getIpAddressgetIpAddress', data);
    Alert.alert('apiv4', JSON.stringify(data));
  }); //free

fetch('https://api64.ipify.org?format=json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log('apiv6_getIpAddressgetIpAddress', data);
    Alert.alert('apiv6', JSON.stringify(data));
  });  //free
```

Answer (score 0):

### If you are using @react-native-community/netinfo

```
import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo";

     useEffect(() => {
            getIpAddress()
            }, []);
        
        const getIpAddress = async () => {
            try {
              const state = await NetInfo.fetch();
              
              if (state.isConnected && state. Details) {
                const ipAddress = state.details.ipAddress;
                console.log('IP Address:', ipAddress);
              } else {
                console.log('Not connected to the internet');
              }
            } catch (error) {
              console.error('Error getting IP address:', error);
            }
          };
```

Answer (score -1):

this is the community package for this.
[@react-native-community/netinfo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/netinfo)

```
import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo";
// Subscribe
const unsubscribe = NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {
  console.log("Connection type", state.type);
  console.log("Is connected?", state.isConnected);
});

// Unsubscribe
unsubscribe();
NetInfo.fetch().then(state => {
  console.log("Connection type", state.type);
  console.log("Is connected?", state.isConnected);
});
```

to get public IP address use this

```
import publicIP from 'react-native-public-ip';
 
publicIP()
  .then(ip => {
    console.log(ip);
    // '47.122.71.234'
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
    // 'Unable to get IP address.'
  });
```

Comment: But this package does not return Public IP Address. Is there a way to get Public IP Address ...like the one you get when you type "my ip" in google ?